# How can I make the gallery circular in jCoverFlip plugin jQuery?

Tags: jquery, gallery, image-gallery, circular-reference

i am using jCoverFlip (http://www.jcoverflip.com/) plugin for a gallery in my site. What I want to do, is to make this gallery circular. Does anyone know how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $('#flip').jcoverflip('next', 1, true);
});
```

next( [by=1], [wrapAround=true], [callback], [originalEvent={}])